# Can Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0 + WAMP like AppServ co-exist

Tags: apache-2.2, php, iis

I need to install the "Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0" which included IIS + PHP etc, and already have my std WAMP (AppServ) installed.

I realise I need to change the de port for one of them to 88 or 8080 etc (prob MS product) but I am unsure of how PHP file associations may change and affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the port of one of them, you should be fine. File associations only play a role for an editor or something like that in an interactive session.

If you contact your system via the port of WAMP, the WAMP Apache will execute a PHP file, and in the case of the MWP port, IIS will do this.

Comment: Thanks Sven, I was ok with the ports but unsure re association issue if any - your reply appreciated